# Javascript normal Array value and Array value created by match function comparison

Tags: javascript, arrays, match

I have issue with two type of arrays value comparison, here is

```
  tagNames = [];

            tagNames.push('61');
            cmt_wrds = '‏‏61'.replace(/[`~!@#$%^&*()_|+\-=?;:'",،؛«».<>\{\}\[\]\\\/]/gi, ' ').match(/\S+/g);


            if ( tagNames[0] == cmt_wrds[0] ) { // issue is here
                console.log('yes'); // --> nothing
            };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you log your variables you will see that they are a bit different. It puts

```
'\u200f'
```

symbol which is the [**Right-To-Left Mark**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-to-left_mark).

```js
var tagNames = [];

 tagNames.push('61');
 cmt_wrds = '‏‏61'.replace(/[`~!@#$%^&*()_|+\-=?;\u200f:'",،؛«».<>\{\}\[\]\\\/]/gi, ' ').match(/\S+/g);

console.log(tagNames);
console.log(cmt_wrds);

console.log(tagNames[0] === cmt_wrds[0]); // returns false, because they are different
```

Comment: How should is prevent teh symbole? any solution?

Comment: @RaminRabii add an `\u200f` in the regex.See the example

Comment: Thanks so much. it was that

Answer (score 1):

Batter use with some varibale to give ah input data It will solve your problem.

```js
(function () {
   tagNames = [];

                tagNames.push('61');
  var datas ="61";//variable declaration
                cmt_wrds = datas.replace(/[`~!@#$%^&*()_|+\-=?;:'",،؛«».<>\{\}\[\]\\\/]/gi, ' ').match(/\S+/g);

 

                if ( tagNames[0] == cmt_wrds[0]) { // issue is here
                    console.log('yes'); // --> nothing
                };
  
  })()
```

Answer (score 0):

If your show their length, here is the difference.

`tagNames[0].length` is 2

`cmt_wrds[0].length` is 4

```js
tagNames = [];

            tagNames.push('61');
            cmt_wrds = '‏‏61'.replace(/[`~!@#$%^&*()_|+\-=?;:'",،؛«».<>\{\}\[\]\\\/]/gi, ' ').match(/\S+/g);


            if ( tagNames[0] == cmt_wrds[0] ) { // issue is here
                console.log('yes'); // --> nothing
            };
console.log(tagNames[0].length);
console.log(cmt_wrds[0].length);
```